# how to handle 2 zone with react-dropzone

Tags: reactjs, dropzone, react-dropzone

I need to use 2 differents dropzones in one component for storing 2 different files withe useDropeZone version.
I'm trying with onDropAccepted and retrieve event with input id...but the id never change.

i have 2 dropezone like that :

```
<div {...getRootProps({style})}>
<input id={'new_logo_input'} {...getInputProps()} />
<p>Drop logo (jpg,png)</p>
</div>
<div {...getRootProps({style})}>

<input id={'new_stamp_input'} {...getInputProps()} />
<p>Drop stamp (jpg,png)</p>
</div>
```

and useDropeZone like that :

```
const { fileRejections, getRootProps, getInputProps, isDragActive, isDragReject, isDragAccept} = useDropzone({
onDropAccepted: (files,event)=>{
console.log(files,event.target.id )
}
})
```

But the event.target.id return allways 'new_stamp_inout'.....!!!

any one can help me ?

Thank's a lot